# How do I refresh an array full of returned values of method calls?

Tags: c#, arrays

In C#, I have a string array that I have written full full of "getter" method calls. They call methods in another class so that the array is populated with the needed strings. It looks something like this:

```
string[] mCalls = {c.get1(), c.get2(), c.get3()};
```

I'm sure this situation could apply to any program. However, in my program the variables these methods return are initially set with the string `"Unchecked"` - thus filling this example array with Unchecked 3 times. As my program goes on and things are checked, the values of the string variables get changed within the class they're in. I've been simply re-calling the getter methods at appropriate times to change what's in my array, like this:

```
mCalls[0] = c.get1();
mCalls[1] = c.get2();
mCalls[2] = c.get3();
```

I don't really like this. It seems inevitable that one day I'll have to change something, and if that happens I will have to manually do the tedious work of changing all of the indexing throughout my program. If this happens to be the best way I'm fine with that, but I assume there are better ways. So, in any case, **is there a way** to "refresh" the values in an array that is set up like this? And if so, what is it?

Comment: You can make mCalls a property and the getter returns an array that is the result of the method calls. This way you only need to update the getter should anything change

Comment: You could make an overarching method that takes `mCalls` as input (or a ref) and then runs each other method inside it. This is technically the same as what you are doing now, but requires less repeated code so that
`mCalls[0] = c.get1();

mCalls[1] = c.get2();

mCalls[2] = c.get3();`

can be replaced with
`GetMCalls(ref mCalls); ` (GetMCalls in an example method name)

Comment: You do not have an array full of method calls. You have an array full of strings where the strings originated from a method call. The method call doesnt exist in your array.

Comment: Also to be clear, the array does not *contain* calls to the methods. That would imply some kind of function pointer as per C/C++ or unsafe C#. The array index contains the returned value of the method calls.

Comment: @user9993 or a delegate in the C# world, such as Func<T> or Action.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done much coding so I'm a bit rusty on the terms. Would my question be more accurate if I said "an array where I have written method calls"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
public string[] MCalls
{
    get
    {
        return new string[]{c.get1(), c.get2(), c.get3()};
    }
    private set;
}
```

and then use MCalls as if it is a regular variable whenever you want to access the arrays

Comment: In my code, I couldn't make this work in my `Main`, so I put it into the class with all the variables, made it private, and replaced the `c.getx()` with the variable names themselves. I made a string[] method like `getMCalls()` that returns the array. I had to take out `private set;`. Anyway, thanks for the help @Gordon, I forgot I could do that!

Answer (score 1):

You could change your array to contain functions instead of strings like this:

```
Func<string>[] mCalls = { c.get1, c.get2, c.get3...};
```

And then use it this way:

```
string c2 = mCalls[1]();
```

But note that this way *every* access is a method call. I'm not sure what you are really trying to achieve, there may be better overall designs than this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options:

Create an array of lambdas:

```
var mCalls = new Func<object, string>[] {
    (object o) => o.ToString() ,
    (object o) => o.GetHashCode().ToString(),
    (object o) => o.GetType().ToString(),
 };
```

If the input to each lambda is the same you can create a lambda that returns an array:

```
 Func<object, string[]> GetValues = (object o) => new string[] 
 {
    o.ToString() ,
    o.GetHashCode().ToString(),
    o.GetType().ToString(),
};
```

Then just reload the array by calling the lambda:

```
mCalls = GetValues(c);
```

Note that it isn't technically *refreshing* the array, it's creating a *new* array.  If you need to keep the array the same but just update the values you'd ned to loop through the array and assign the values by index.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is loop thorugh with reflection and get all methods from the class and from here you can get a list of method names. With this list you can assign to an array or run the methods by name or whatever. You can also filter the list to get your specific method names only:

```
var methodNames = typeof(MyClass).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                            .Select(x => x.Name)
                            .Distinct()
                            .OrderBy(x => x);
```

To call the methods:

```
foreach(var method in methodNames)
{
    typeof(MyClass).GetMethod(method).Invoke(t, new[] { "world" });
}
```